# 2GP managed package: cannot create a patch release

Tags: managed-package, isv, versioning, patch, 2gp

We have an "extension" package that integrates our managed 1GP with a third party managed 1GP. This "extension" package is realized as a managed 2GP.

We hit a problem when trying to create a patch release for the "extension" package - each time we tried to create the patch version using a command line like this:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "Our Package" --installationkey "SomeKey" \
    --definitionfile config/our-scratch-def.json --wait 120 --codecoverage
```

We would see the following output:

```
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 7200 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='Initializing'
Request in progress. Sleeping 30 seconds. Will wait a total of 7170 more seconds before timing out. Current Status='Verifying features and settings'
ERROR running force:package:version:create: Communities: Chatter Community domain must be set prior to enabling Communities
```

The "extension" package doesn't actually include any community-related metadata, so this is really confusing. The required scratch def does enable Community features, but only because of the needs of one or other dependency 1GP.

config/our-scratch-def.json:

```
{
  "orgName": "Our Org Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "hasSampleData": false,
  "features": [
    "API",
    "AuthorApex",
    "Communities",
    "DebugApex",
    "PlatformEncryption",
    "ProcessBuilder",
    "Sites",
    "Workflow"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "nameSettings": {
      "enableMiddleName": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true
    },
    "emailAdministrationSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
    },
    "pathAssistantSettings": {
      "pathAssistantEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "namespace": "namespace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "Our Package",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.1.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "A description",
      "ancestorId": "Our Package@1.0.0",
      "definitionFile": "config/our-scratch-def.json",
      "postInstallScript": "namespace.OurInstaller",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Core Package@2.2.0"
        },
        {
          "package": "Third Party Package@5.10.4.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "force-unpackaged"
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "Core Package@2.2.0": "04t0..."
    "Third Party Package@5.10.4.1": "04t4...",
    "Our Package": "0Ho3...",
    "Our Package@1.0.0": "04t3..."
  }
}
```

Has anyone seen this issue? Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the error message is a **complete red herring**; this is nothing to do with communities and all to do with **not** having had patch version creation enabled on the package's namespace org. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_patch_version.htm) (something to stumble upon and the reason I'm posting this Q&A to make it easier to find):

> To enable patch versioning, log a case in the Salesforce Partner Community and request patch versioning be enabled in the org where you created the namespace for this package

Something else not mentioned in any documentation I can find, but apparently (according to Salesforce Support, with no citation of any documentation):

> You need to have your Application/s passed the Security Review [for Salesforce to] proceed with your request

A very confusing, undocumented requirement; it's not like you can do anything extra in creating a patch release than you can do when creating major or minor version releases (indeed, quite the opposite). In the end we were forced to create a minor version release instead of a patch, which doesn't reflect the purpose of the release.