# 2gp Patching is Failing Even When the Only Change is a Comment

Tags: managed-package, patch, second-generation-packaging

I'm currently trying to get patching working for our 2gp managed package but it's consistently hitting the same set of errors around report folders and report filters (see screenshot). Now I know what you're going to say *"Hey Shane, why don't you just fix the errors? Duh"* - I know, but there're multiple layers to this:

- Firstly, it doesn't seem to matter what changes there are in the package, this error will blow. The screenshot below was when I tried to patch a small change I made to a comment(I only patched a comment to see what it would blow up for, a comment change is not the need for the patch).
- I have tried to remove the filters on the errant reports but regardless, these errors still fire as if the reports were never updated
- As per [this stack exchange question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/317449/99547), the package version I'm patching has been Security Reviewed *and* patching is enabled in our PBO org

So my question is twofold -

1. **Why won't sfdx patch a version that is essentially identical to its parent package?** I imagine the patch process is different from initial packaging but surely something that packaged OK can be patched with something as minor as a comment? We have packaged many times since with no problems.
2. **Am I missing something here to get this to work?**

The project.json is below followed by the packaging command

**sfdx-project.json**

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "PackageXY",
            "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
            "postInstallScript": "PostInstall",
            "ancestorId": "PackageXY@1.9.0-8",
            "versionName": "1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.9.1.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "xy",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "51.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "PackageXY@1.9.0-8": "04tXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

**Package Command**

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "PackageXY" --versionname "COMMIT#-patch" --versiondescription "Desc" --targetdevhubusername "user@email.com" --installationkey "XXXXX" --codecoverage --wait 25
```

[image: Error List]

Comment: Are you sure patching is enabled on the correct org? Is your PBO your Dev Hub (as required by Salesforce for ISV partners)?

Comment: Hey @PhilW, it's a fair question but yeah, I double-checked that the PBO is our Dev Hub and I double-checked the Org ID I put in the case to have it enabled. It's the right org

Comment: Whoops... I forgot: don't you need to enable it in the namespace org?

Comment: Ahhhhh, I did not know that and I'm 90% sure it's not enabled there so I must give this one a go. Thanks, @PhilW. I Will update when I get something from SF. Is that in the docs? Seems like a silly miss from me but I don't remember seeing it.

Comment: It's mentioned in the other Q&A you cited.

Comment: Great * *facepalm* *

Comment: Feel free to upvote that other Q&A if it solves the issue :)

Comment: Still waiting on that support case to have patching enabled in the Namespace org. I had already upvoted that other answer but hopefully once this comes through we'll be flying. If that doesn't I'll probably reopen this question.
Cheers @PhilW

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't resolved. After enabling patching in the Namespace we still had the same errors (we actually had more). Most were pointing to reports so I deprecated them but we've come to a new error that I can't just deprecate. I opened a new ticket to explain here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366841/2gp-patching-fails-due-to-missing-salesprocess-value-even-though-same-code-packa

Comment: Bummer. I saw. Have you raised a case with Salesforce? If you are a partner then you could get a technical guidance call (can't remember the actual term).

Comment: Yeah we are so it's probably the route we'll need to go down. It would be nice to get them to say "this isn't possible because of how we treat patching" but I'm not sure that will happen. The maybe we can, maybe we can't is the biggest pain tbh. Cheers for the help on it though, @PhilW

Comment: Patching is *supposed* to be supported for 2GPs. Good luck!