# Picklist value: Advertisement in picklist: AccountSource not found

Tags: managed-package, picklist

There is something really strange, I got these errors after try to create patch update version

```
vctqs1@Thus-MBP erp-salesforce % sf package version create --package 'Manabie User' --installation-key password123 -w 10 -v pbo_manabie
(node:8032) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 ›   Warning: @salesforce/cli update available from 2.12.9 to 2.14.6.
Version create.... Create version status: Error
Error (1): Multiple errors occurred: 
(1) Account.Household: Picklist value: Advertisement in picklist: AccountSource not found
(2) Contact.Parent: Picklist value: Advertisement in picklist: LeadSource not found
(3) Contact.Staff: Picklist value: Advertisement in picklist: LeadSource not found
(4) Contact.Student: Picklist value: Advertisement in picklist: LeadSource not found
(5) Account.Location: Picklist value: Account%2EAccountSource in picklist: AccountSource not found
```

I tried to create new package versio from 0.4.0.0 to 0.5.0.0 it works fine with current metadata
Then try to create with `exactly same` metadata from 0.5.0.0 to 0.5.1.0 it breaks and appear those errors.
Although `LeadSource` and `AccountSource` already exist here in my screenshot
[image]
Also I really confuse why 0.5.0.0 was created successfully without anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out because we have not enabled `patching` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_patch_version.htm

> To enable patch versioning, log a case in the Salesforce Partner Community and request patch versioning be enabled in the org where you created the namespace for this package.

and `StandardValueSets` is not accepted in patching version
This is known issue https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000mNTs0AAG/the-standardvaluesets-are-not-supported-correctly-when-creating-patch-package-versions

Reference [2GP managed package: cannot create a patch release](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317448/2gp-managed-package-cannot-create-a-patch-release?noredirect=1&lq=1)